# Data is not Retrieving from Firebase Firestore into Arraylist in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a quiz app. So, in this app user first of all tap on play button and he has to choose category and then he has to choose no of questions and quiz will start.

In quiz activity, problem is that data is not retrieving from firebase firestore in the arraylist. If i did some problem please give the solution.

Below is my code of Main Activity.java where user tap on play button.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        binding.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,chooseCategory_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        binding.exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now user has to choose category. Below is the code of chooseCategoryActivity.java.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class chooseCategory_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<chooseCategoryModal> chooseCategoryArrayList;
    chooseCategoryAdapter chooseCategoryAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    CollectionReference ref;

    ActivityChooseCategory2Binding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChooseCategory2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        chooseCategoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Categories");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        binding.categoriesRv.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        binding.categoriesRv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        chooseCategoryAdapter = new chooseCategoryAdapter(chooseCategoryArrayList, chooseCategory_Activity.this);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        ref = db.collection("Category");

        ref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot value, FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d("ErrorCollection", error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }

                chooseCategoryArrayList.clear();
                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot: value.getDocuments()){
                    chooseCategoryModal modal = snapshot.toObject(chooseCategoryModal.class);
                    modal.setCategoryId(snapshot.getId());
                    chooseCategoryArrayList.add(modal);
                }
                chooseCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        binding.categoriesRv.setAdapter(chooseCategoryAdapter);

    }
}
```

Below is the code of chooseCategoryModal.java.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class chooseCategoryModal {

    String categoryName, categoryId;

    public chooseCategoryModal() {
    }

    public chooseCategoryModal(String categoryName, String categoryId) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```

Below is the code of chooseCategoryAdapter.java.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class chooseCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<chooseCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<chooseCategoryModal> chooseCategorArrayList;
    Context context;
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
    static int noOfQuestions = 0;
    Boolean cardColorCyan = false;
    String categoryName, categoryId;

    public chooseCategoryAdapter(ArrayList<chooseCategoryModal> chooseCategorArrayList, Context context) {
        this.chooseCategorArrayList = chooseCategorArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.choose_category_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(chooseCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.categ_card.setCardBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
        categoryName = chooseCategorArrayList.get(position).getCategoryName();
        categoryId = chooseCategorArrayList.get(position).getCategoryId();
        holder.categoryName.setText(categoryName);
        holder.categ_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetTheme);
                View bsView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                        inflate(R.layout.choose_ques_bottomsheet_layout,
                                view.findViewById(R.id.choose_ques_bottomsheet));

                bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);

                CardView card5 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.five_ques);
                CardView card10 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.ten_ques);
                CardView card15 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.fifteen_ques);
                CardView card20 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.twenty_ques);
                CardView card25 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.twentyfive_ques);
                CardView card30 = bsView.findViewById(R.id.thirty_ques);

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.five_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 5;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.ten_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 10;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.fifteen_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 15;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.twenty_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 20;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.twentyfive_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 25;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.thirty_ques).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (cardColorCyan) {
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            cardColorCyan = false;
                            noOfQuestions = 0;
                        } else {
                            card30.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            card5.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card10.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card15.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card20.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));
                            card25.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.light_grey));

                            cardColorCyan = true;
                            noOfQuestions = 30;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.play_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (noOfQuestions != 0){
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Quiz_Activity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("CC_noOfQuestion",noOfQuestions);
                            intent.putExtra("CC_quizCategory",categoryName);
                            intent.putExtra("CC_categoryId",categoryId);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Choose No of Questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                bsView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        noOfQuestions = 0;
                        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bsView);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chooseCategorArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView categoryName;
        CardView categ_card;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            categ_card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categ_card);
        }
    }

    private int getRandomColor(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        return color;
   }

}
```

Data is not updating in realtime. This is also happened in chooseCategoryActivity but after implementing the below dependency it solved.

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
```

Below is the code of quizActivity.java.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class Quiz_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int noOfQuestions;
    String quizCategory, categoryId;
    ArrayList<QuestionModal> questionModalArrayList;
    Random random;
    int currentScore = 0, incorrectScore = 0, questionNo = 1;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;


    int index = 0;
    QuestionModal question;


    ActivityQuizBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityQuizBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        random = new Random();
        questionModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        noOfQuestions = getIntent().getIntExtra("CC_noOfQuestion", 0);
        quizCategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("CC_quizCategory");
        categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CC_categoryId");

        addQuestions();

        binding.optionA.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
        binding.optionB.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
        binding.optionC.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
        binding.optionD.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
    }

    private void addQuestions() {
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        int rand = random.nextInt(5);

        firestore.collection("Category")
                .document(categoryId)
                .collection("Questions")
                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("index", rand)
                .orderBy("index")
                .limit(noOfQuestions)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().size() < 5) {
                            firestore.collection("Category")
                                    .document(categoryId)
                                    .collection("Questions")
                                    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("index", rand)
                                    .orderBy("index")
                                    .limit(noOfQuestions)
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                                QuestionModal questionModal = snapshot.toObject(QuestionModal.class);
                                                questionModalArrayList.add(questionModal);

                                                Toast.makeText(Quiz_Activity.this, "Success 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                            setNextQuestion();
                                        }
                                    });

                            Log.d("question success 1","question success 1");
                        } else {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                QuestionModal questionModal = snapshot.toObject(QuestionModal.class);
                                questionModalArrayList.add(questionModal);

                                Toast.makeText(Quiz_Activity.this, "Success 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            setNextQuestion();
                            Log.d("question success 2","question success 2");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


    private void showScoreBoard() {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Quiz_Activity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Score Board");
        dialog.show();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz_Activity.this, ScoreBoard_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("quizCategory", quizCategory);
                intent.putExtra("noOfQuestions", noOfQuestions);
                intent.putExtra("correctAnswers", currentScore);
                intent.putExtra("incorrectAnswers", incorrectScore);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }


    private void setNextQuestion() {
        if (index < questionModalArrayList.size()) {
            question = questionModalArrayList.get(index);

            binding.questionNo.setText("Question " + questionNo++);
            binding.progress.setText("Progress: " + (index + 1) + "/" + noOfQuestions);
            binding.question.setText(question.getQuestion());
            binding.optionA.setText(question.getOptionA());
            binding.optionB.setText(question.getOptionB());
            binding.optionC.setText(question.getOptionC());
            binding.optionD.setText(question.getOptionD());
        } else {
            showScoreBoard();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option_A:

                setCardClickable();
                checkAnswer(binding.optionA, binding.opACard);
                setHandler();
                break;

            case R.id.option_B:

                setCardClickable();
                checkAnswer(binding.optionB, binding.opBCard);
                setHandler();
                break;

            case R.id.option_C:

                setCardClickable();
                checkAnswer(binding.optionC, binding.opCCard);
                setHandler();
                break;

            case R.id.option_D:

                setCardClickable();
                checkAnswer(binding.optionD, binding.opDCard);
                setHandler();
                break;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void checkAnswer(TextView option, MaterialCardView card) {

        if (option.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                .equals(question.getCorrectAnswer().trim().toLowerCase())) {

            currentScore++;
            card.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.green));

        } else {
            incorrectScore++;
            card.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.red));

            if (binding.optionA.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                    .equals(question.getCorrectAnswer().trim().toLowerCase())) {
                binding.opACard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.green));
            } else if (binding.optionB.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                    .equals(question.getCorrectAnswer().trim().toLowerCase())) {
                binding.opBCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.green));
            } else if (binding.optionC.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                    .equals(question.getCorrectAnswer().trim().toLowerCase())) {
                binding.opCCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.green));
            } else if (binding.optionD.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                    .equals(question.getCorrectAnswer().trim().toLowerCase())) {
                binding.opDCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.green));
            }

        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void resetCardStrokeColors() {
        binding.opACard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.main_color));
        binding.opBCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.main_color));
        binding.opCCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.main_color));
        binding.opDCard.setStrokeColor(getColorStateList(R.color.main_color));
    }

    private void setCardClickable() {
        binding.opACard.setClickable(false);
        binding.opBCard.setClickable(false);
        binding.opCCard.setClickable(false);
        binding.opDCard.setClickable(false);
    }

    private void setHandler() {
        if (index <= questionModalArrayList.size()) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    resetCardStrokeColors();
                    index++;
                    setNextQuestion();
                }
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            showScoreBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code of QuestionModal.java.

```
package com.example.capitalcamp;

public class QuestionModal {

    String Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, QuestionId;
    Number index;

    public QuestionModal(){

    }

    public QuestionModal( String question, String optionA, String optionB,
                         String optionC, String optionD, String correctAnswer, String questionId, Number Index) {
        Question = question;
        OptionA = optionA;
        OptionB = optionB;
        OptionC = optionC;
        OptionD = optionD;
        CorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
        QuestionId = questionId;
        index = Index;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return Question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        Question = question;
    }

    public String getOptionA() {
        return OptionA;
    }

    public void setOptionA(String optionA) {
        OptionA = optionA;
    }

    public String getOptionB() {
        return OptionB;
    }

    public void setOptionB(String optionB) {
        OptionB = optionB;
    }

    public String getOptionC() {
        return OptionC;
    }

    public void setOptionC(String optionC) {
        OptionC = optionC;
    }

    public String getOptionD() {
        return OptionD;
    }

    public void setOptionD(String optionD) {
        OptionD = optionD;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return CorrectAnswer;
    }

    public void setCorrectAnswer(String correctAnswer) {
        CorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public String getQuestionId() {
        return QuestionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(String questionId) {
        QuestionId = questionId;
    }

    public Number getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(Number index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Below is the link of screenshot of firestore database.

[Firestore Database Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOGTq.jpg)

[Firestore Database Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190Cm.jpg)

In this quiz activity, problem is that data is not retrieving from firebase firestore in the arraylist. If i did some problem please give the solution.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Such as Alex says, I suggest you to make a [mre] but **MINIMAL** example